# Query database fails at GetOne

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Optimisation

In the section `Dynamic MetaDesc in a list of articles by category`

I have followed, I get a fatal error stating that the `Call to a member function GetOne() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\zoomla\includes\application.php on line 391`

Could someone help me deal with this ?Thank you. BTW, the previous section doesn't fit with Joomla 2.5 Could you help me on that too ?

How about `Add Heading Tags in the Titles for More Relevance` ???? for Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

That seems for older versions of Joomla.

This code snippet:

```
if (strcasecmp($_GET['view'],'category')==0) {         
   $description = $database->GetOne("SELECT description FROM #__categories WHERE id={$_GET['id']}");       
}
```

Is most likely the same as (in Joomla 2.5):

```
if (strcasecmp($_GET['view'],'category')==0) {
   $db = JFactory::getDBO();
   $db->setQuery("SELECT description FROM #__categories WHERE id=".(int)$_GET['id']);
   $description = $db->loadResult();       
}
```

Please note that my code is not tested.

Comment: Isn't the titles already tagged with <h2> in Joomla 2.5 Category Blog Layout?

Answer (score 0):

That article isn't relevant for Joomla! 2.5.  For starters the category view already includes the meta description and keywords if they exists in the `view.html.php`

```
if ($this->category->metadesc)
{
    $this->document->setDescription($this->category->metadesc);
}
elseif (!$this->category->metadesc && $this->params->get('menu-meta_description'))
{
    $this->document->setDescription($this->params->get('menu-meta_description'));
}
if ($this->category->metakey)
{
    $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->category->metakey);
}
elseif (!$this->category->metakey && $this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords'))
{
    $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords'));
}
```

The same applies to the section for adding heading tags to article titles:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
    <h2>
    <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && !empty($this->item->readmore_link)) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you do want to make changes to the way the output is done you should create [template overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for `com_content` in your template.